# python tkinter module Label widget wrapped in oop

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am practicing on my personal project to create oop from tkinter module.  I have written a code block where I try to create Label widget by imperative code line, then within a class.

```
from tkinter import *

app=Tk()
app.geometry('500x300')
Button(app,width=13,height=1,text='scrape').pack()
var_str=StringVar()
var_str='result 001 ...'
Label(app,width=33,height=1,text='res',textvariable=var_str).pack()

class label():
    def __init__(self,master,var_text):
        self.label=Label(master,width=33,height=1,textvariable=var_text).pack()

lbl_one=label(app,var_str)
app.mainloop()
```

The strangeness is if I comment out `Label(app,width=33,height=1,text='res',textvariable=var_str).pack()` then my object instantiation does not work out.
I would like to have a clear answer why `lbl_one` object gives same text result as with Label(app...) line?

Comment: You are modifying the value of var_str to 'result 001 ...'
remove this line and use the value= command to assign an initial value

`var_str = StringVar(value='Hellow from var_str')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you probably forgot that u put StringVar at top then changed it to string which not work.

```
var_str=StringVar(master=app, value="res")
```

replace that line to this and comment the first label's line then the object would work fine.